# Bookshelf.js: one-to-many relationship setup

Tags: bookshelf.js

I'm using Bookshelf for an ORM with MySQL. I've got endpoints and organizations. Each endpoint belongs to an organization, and an organization has many endpoints. I'm trying to fetch a list of endpoints with their associated organization(s.) This is returning the following error:

"A valid target model must be defined for the endpoint belongsTo relation"

Here's my fetchAll request:

```
Endpoint
            .where('organization_id', req.user.attributes.organization_id)
            .fetchAll({require: true,withRelated: ['settings', 'organization']})
            .then((endpoints) => {
                ReS(res, {
                    endpoints
                }, 200);
            })
```

Here's my endpoint model:

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf_instance');
const Organization = require('./organization');
const Settings = require('./endpoint_settings');
const Group = require('./endpoint_group');

module.exports = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'endpoint',
    organization () {
        return this.belongsTo(Organization, 'id');
    },
    settings () {
        return this.hasOne(Settings, 'id');
    },
    group () {
        return this.belongsToMany(Group, 'map_endpoint_endpoint_group');
    }
});
```

Here's my organization model:

```
'use strict';

const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf_instance');
const Endpoint = require('./endpoint');
const User = require('./user');
const Group = require('./endpoint_group');

module.exports = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'organization',
    endpoints () {
        return this.hasMany(Endpoint, 'organization_id');
    },
    users () {
        return this.hasMany(User, 'organization_id');
    },
    groups () {
        return this.hasMany(Group, 'organization_id');
    }
});
```

Comment: No point in specifying `organization_id` in the Organization model's `hasMany` relations. That's already the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `id` from the Endpoint model's relation specifications, since that seems to be the primary key, not the foreign key. The foreign key is also `organization_id` by default which is what you want. It should match what you have in the opposite relation (`hasMany` in this case).

From the documentation, the second argument to `belongsTo` is the:

> ForeignKey in this model. By default, the foreignKey is assumed to be the singular form of the Target model's tableName, followed by _id.

The target model's table name is `organization`, which means the foreign key is `organization_id` by default.